# Canvas takes up space of parent div

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I've done a lot of searching, but I am unable to solve this problem I'm having.

I have a `canvas` nested in a `div`, with the intention of having the `div` serve as the background for the `canvas`, so that I can draw objects on it and whatnot.

When I run my code, the canvas appears side by side with the div, and I am unsure what to change to fix it.

```js
// html
<body>
    <div id="root">
        <div id='board'>
           <div>test</div>
           <canvas></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

// css
#board {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    width: 640px;
    height: 640px;
}

// js
let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

canvas.width = canvas.offsetWidth
canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight
```

Looked up similar questions on here with little success. Insight would be very appreciated!

Comment: You need absolute position on the canvas

Comment: Sheesh. I feel dumb for not seeing the answer that simple. Thanks a lot. Did you want to answer the question officially so I could mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this styling for example, to center your canvas and then add more items as you need to the background div.

```
canvas {
  background-color: green;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  align-self: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  left: 50%;
}
```

I added an image of the result.

[image]